# Combining 2 videos by ffmpeg via c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ffmpeg

I need to combine two video file using ffmpeg. 
Can you help me? I tried cat command, It won't works well.

```
 ProcessStartInfo info1 = new ProcessStartInfo(@"e:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe", 
 @"cat e:\cars1.mpg e:\cars2.mpg | ffmpeg -f mpeg -i - -vcodec copy -acodec copy e:\merged.mpg");
```

Give me some suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok finally i found answer for my own question.

I just set a batch file that consists of copy command.

```
ProcessStartInfo info1 = new ProcessStartInfo("app.bat");
```

**app.bat**

The app.bat file consists of the following command. It is for windows only.

```
copy e:\cars1.mpg /b + e:\cars2.mpg /b e:\output.mpg /b
```

it merges the two video file. But only a problem is, it takes only the running timing of first video file only. But video runs smoothly.